# how to add nesbot/carbon to magento 2

Tags: magento2, datetime

I want to add [nesbot/carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) ti magento 2.3.5 and i don't know how. I'd be appreciated for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon

All you need to do is composer require the package from the Magento root folder. It may not be installable if it has un-met dependency requirements:

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Then in your php code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Carbon\Carbon;
```